# Getting values of each number to be not more 90

Tags: python

I have a code which generates random number and put them in a list. The total of the values of these number must follow a defined value (in this case 6066). The numbers in the list also have to be a certain amount, meaning that i want 95 numbers to be generated randomly into a list, and the total of the values of these 95 numbers in the list is equals to 6066.

The code :

```
import random

def num(n, total):

    
    dividers = sorted(random.sample(range(1, total), n - 1))
    j= [a - b for a, b in zip(dividers + [total], [0] + dividers)]
    
    
    return j
    

    
i=num(95,6066)

 
print (i)
```

The problem im facing is that i do not want any of the values of the 95 numbers in the list to exceed 85. How do i do this?

I have tried:

```
import random

def num(n, total):


dividers = sorted(random.sample(range(1, total), n - 1))
j= [a - b for a, b in zip(dividers + [total], [0] + dividers)]
for k in j:
    if k>85:
        j.remove(k)
    
   

return j



i=num(95,6066)


print (i)
```

But this only removes the number which are more than 85 from the list, i need to have 95 numbers in the list and total up to 6066

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: A uniform distribution of numbers `0-85` is going to average around `~4100` So what does random mean to you? What kind of distribution are you looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution will be to consider the problem like you are trying to distribute 6066 items between 95 buckets and each one has a capacity of 85, so you just loop over the items and each time choose a bucket that is not already full.

Here is a simple implementation. It won't be particularly fast, but it avoids the need to backtrack because there is no possibility of violating the rules (total sum incorrect or individual value exceeds the maximum).

Note that other solutions that are equally valid within your rules may have a different probability distribution, but you have not said anything about what probability distribution you require.

```
import random

def num(n, total, maxv):

    if total > n * maxv:
        raise ValueError("incompatible requirements")

    vals = [0 for _ in range(n)]
    not_full = list(range(n))

    for _ in range(total):
        index = random.choice(not_full)
        vals[index] += 1
        if vals[index] == maxv:
            not_full.remove(index)

    return vals

answer = num(95, 6066, 85)

print(answer)
print(max(answer))
print(sum(answer))
```

Gives:

```
[59, 59, 73, 63, 77, 58, 54, 71, 73, 67, 69, 67, 58, 79, 63, 59, 80, 58, 77, 64, 62, 64, 54, 50, 64, 72, 62, 69, 81, 61, 63, 50, 65, 56, 60, 51, 59, 61, 63, 56, 67, 69, 69, 64, 85, 66, 74, 66, 63, 63, 63, 68, 84, 66, 53, 82, 59, 66, 63, 58, 67, 58, 59, 58, 69, 56, 63, 61, 73, 58, 65, 60, 61, 53, 68, 51, 58, 57, 67, 60, 65, 73, 63, 59, 62, 49, 66, 59, 64, 56, 69, 58, 61, 67, 74]
85
6066
```