# Generating a list of N pseudo-random integers, drawn from a specific range, with the list summing to a specific value

Tags: python, list

In Python:

How can I generate a list of N (e.g. 10) pseudo-random integers, each drawn from a specific range (e.g. between 3 and 9), with the list summing up to a specific value (e.g. 58)?

For this example the solution would look like this:

```
solution = [3, 7, 7, 9, 3, 6, 4, 8, 8, 3]

sum(solution)
58
```

That is, 10 numbers, each between 3 and 9, summing up to 58.

I've tried a solution approaches with `np.random.dirichlet` or `np.random.multinomial` as suggested in related questions here, but these do not allow for choosing the integers from a specific range.

Comment: Surely, if the sum is fixed then it's not a random list? Or at least, there must be one non-random value.

Comment: The list doesn't have to be random. Depending on the chosen N and summing value, there can be multiple solutions and for those the integers that make up the list should/can be chosen pseudo-randomly (i.e. any solution is fine).

Comment: If your difficulty is choosing random numbers you can use random.randrange

Comment: If it's any use there is answer I wrote to a very similar question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62946516/getting-values-of-each-number-to-be-not-more-90

Comment: ... that question was with lower end of the range = 0, but the difference is trivial because for example you can just subtract off 30 from the target and then add 3 to each number at the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import random

N = 10
s = 58
i, j = 3, 9

out = [i] * N

while sum(out) != s:
    idx = random.randint(0, N-1)
    if out[idx] < j:
        out[idx] += 1

print(out)
```

Prints (for example):

```
[9, 7, 6, 4, 5, 8, 3, 5, 5, 6]
```

Comment: It's interesting that on average this favors a distribution high in 5s and 6s and low in 9s and 3s.

Comment: On reflection, I suspect number of ways you can partition 58 into 10 numbers between 3 and 9 is weighted heavily with combinations with more 5s and 6s.

Comment: @MarkMeyer Given that nothing at all has been specified about the desired probability distribution, one could arguably come up with a solution that is entirely deterministic (probability 1 of a certain outcome and 0 of everything else)... though maybe it wouldn't quite be in the spirit of things.

Comment: @MarkMeyer Looking at a distribution of my solution, it seems that 4 should occur most often, followed by 3 and 5.

Comment: @HeapOverflow it seems like the distribution of numbers is on average, much more even than this one. That's interesting — not sure why that is.

Answer (score 0):

One idea I've just had is to initialise a list with n values that are the average value (so, as close to being all the same value as possible) and then randomly select a pair of values and increase one while decreasing the other while ensuring values are kept with the required range, so don't increase/decrease if the value will go out of bounds.

Answer (score 0):

Repeat until success?

```
a = []
while sum(a) != 58:
    a = random.choices(range(3, 10), k=10)
```

Takes about 17 attempts on average.

Comment: How about if you randomly selected 9 numbers, and then the 10th number is `58 - sum(a)`, only having to repeat if that last number is not in range?

Comment: @alaniwi The distribution for that looks very similar (I guess it might be the same, too tired to think now :-). And takes only about 2.4 attempts. So yeah, that might be better.